# Dynamic sign in for Google Drive connector in Logic Apps

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Here I have requirement to list down all the documents from Google drive to some location.Its a continous operartion.

In order to create logic app workflow it is asking to sign in, But my requirement is I have 300+ users I thought of passing OAuth token dynamically to connect to google drive.

Will it be possible to use multiple accounts for single Google drive connector?

[image]

In the second step I have to login to goolge in order to connect to drive, So my requirement is to automate that sign in process. Can anyone help out whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is have the users authorize the connection to google apis, this flow is called Authorization Grant flow of OAUTH 2.0, this flow is implemented in websites or pages with which the users interact.  Logic app is a workflow which needs to have a static token before connecting to the apis. The sign in feature is by design and hou cannot bypass it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Do we have any machanism to generate static token? If yes how we can pass to logic app?

Comment: Well as I mentioned, the inbuilt connector will need you to sign in with an account to authorize the logic app to manage your google drive. So for google drive connector it is not possible. In other cases, you can set up a HTTP trigger in your logic app and accept the token, or you can put azure api management service in front of logic app and intercept the token there